# probability of infinite intersection and limit of each event does not imply nestedness

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $P(\cap_{i\in\mathbb{N}} A_i)=\lim_{i\to\infty}P(A_i)$. Can someone please give me a hint as to how to think of a counterexample in showing that the above statement does not necessarily imply that $A_{i+1}\subset A_i$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is only the probabilities that are equal. An almost trivial counterexample could be the following.

Assume $A_i$'s are all independent events, with $P(A_i)=\frac{1}{i}$. Then clearly $\lim_{i \to \infty} P(A_i) = 0$, and

$$
P(\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i) = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} P(A_i) = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{i} = 0
$$

However, $A_{i+1} \subset A_i$ is not true since these are independent events.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same idea about independence, but couldn't finish the logic.